# jQuery filter for each string that's not null

Tags: javascript, jquery, filter

How would I apply a jQuery filter for every string that's not null?

Basically, I have the following code and would want to make it work for any number of "selectors" that are being set beforehand.

The list of selectors available would be in an array.

```
if (typeselector === '' && colorselector === '') {          
  $('.product').filter(selector).show();
} else if (typeselector === '') {
  $('.product').filter(selector).filter(colorselector).show();
} else if (colorselector === '') {
  $('.product').filter(selector).filter(typeselector).show();
} else {
  $('.product').filter(selector).filter(typeselector).filter(colorselector).show();
}
```

Thanks for any suggestions/help!

Comment: so what is the problem with this code

Comment: One way to simplify it could be - http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/c02cv1fn/1/

Comment: each(function() {...}?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To simplify you can use chaining:

```
var products = $('.product').filter(selector);
if (typeselector !== '') {          
  products = products.filter(typeselector);
}
if (colorselector !== '') {          
  products = products.filter(colorselector);
}
products.show();
```

or even something like this:

```
var products = $('.product').filter(selector);
var selectors = [typeselector, colorselector];

selectors.each(function(selector) {
    if (selector !== '') {
        products = products.filter(selector);
    }
});
products.show();
```